# How to show hibernate sql parameter with values, instead of ?,?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, logging

how to write hibernate sql queries log in log file with values.

Example:-

**Now print queries :-**

```
 select
        employee0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        employee0_.age as age2_0_0_,
        employee0_.dept as dept3_0_0_,
        employee0_.lname as lname4_0_0_,
        employee0_.name as name5_0_0_,
        employee0_.salary as salary6_0_0_ 
    from
        employee employee0_ 
    where
        employee0_.id=?
```

but there is print question mark in last line. 
**i want to print like :-**

```
 select
    employee0_.id as id1_0_0_,
    employee0_.age as age2_0_0_,
    employee0_.dept as dept3_0_0_,
    employee0_.lname as lname4_0_0_,
    employee0_.name as name5_0_0_,
    employee0_.salary as salary6_0_0_ 
from
    employee employee0_ 
where
    employee0_.id=1
```

Comment: @i.bondarenko but in this link print separate log for values , i want to print values where question mark in log file.

Comment: From the answer 
`# Logs the JDBC parameters passed to a query
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace `

Comment: @Hitesh, `i.bondarenko` has answered your question.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I did not get my answer because of there is print separate values in log file like :-

 `6908 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [9]  `

Comment: @Hitesh, that is Hibernate specific implementation. You will have query with the Hibernate Dev team (RedHat) to check how to possibly do it.